# Dynamic record per page for ajax pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement ajax pagination.Everything is alright but i am having difficulties with record per page.In my script `$recordsPerPage` is fixed but i want to make it dynamic so that users can select the number of records per page through provided options .How to attain this based on my code ?

```
$query="select * FROM ac WHERE status=1 order by id asc";
$res    = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$count  = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$page = (int) (!isset($_REQUEST['pageId']) ? 1 :$_REQUEST['pageId']);
$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
$recordsPerPage = 4;
$start = ($page-1) * $recordsPerPage;
$adjacents = "2";

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($count/$recordsPerPage);
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;   
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";
        if ($page > 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($prev)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($prev).");'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";   
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     

            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                for($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lpm1)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lpm1).");'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lastpage)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lastpage).");'>$lastpage</a>";   

           }
           elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
           {
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"1\"\" onClick='changePagination(1);'>1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"2\"\" onClick='changePagination(2);'>2</a>";
               $pagination.= "...";
               for($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
               {
                   if($counter == $page)
                       $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                   else
                       $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
               }
               $pagination.= "..";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lpm1)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lpm1).");'>$lpm1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($lastpage)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($lastpage).");'>$lastpage</a>";   
           }
           else
           {
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"1\"\" onClick='changePagination(1);'>1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=\"2\"\" onClick='changePagination(2);'>2</a>";
               $pagination.= "..";
               for($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
               {
                   if($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                   else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($counter)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
               }
           }
        }
        if($page < $counter - 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"#Page=".($next)."\" onClick='changePagination(".($next).");'>Next &raquo;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Next &raquo;</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";       
    }

if(isset($_POST['pageId']) && !empty($_POST['pageId']))
{
    $id=$_POST['pageId'];
}
else
{
    $id='0';
}
$query="select * FROM ac WHERE status=1 order by id asc
limit ".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$start).",$recordsPerPage";
```

Ajax:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    changePagination('0');    
    });
    function changePagination(pageId){

         $(".flash").show();
         $(".flash").fadeIn(800).html
             ('Loading <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
         var dataString = 'pageId='+ pageId  ;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "page.php",
               data: dataString,
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
               $(".flash").hide();
               $("#pageData").html(result);
               }
          });
    }
    </script>
```

Options:

```
<select name="rp">
<option value="p1">5</option>
<option value="p2">10</option>            
<option value="p3">15</option>
<option value="p4">20</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: off topic, but merging php, html, javascript increases unnecessary complexity. [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentPage = '0';
$(document).ready(function(){
changePagination();    
});
function changePagination(pageId){
     currentPage = !pageId ? currentPage : pageId;
     $(".flash").show();
     $(".flash").fadeIn(800).html
         ('Loading <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
     var dataString = {pageId: currentPage, recordsPerPage: $('select[name="rp"] option:selected').html()};
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "page.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(result){
           $(".flash").hide();
           $("#pageData").html(result);
           }
      });
}
</script>
```

And in your php script, read the value sent in the `recordsPerPage` parameter:

```
$recordsPerPage = (int) (!isset($_REQUEST['recordsPerPage']) ? 4 :$_REQUEST['recordsPerPage']);
```

Comment: onchange should i call the changePagination() function with empty arguments ?If i do so a new problem arise for 1st page the record per page changes according to selected option but if i go to the next pages  the record per page becomes  fixed which  is 4 !how to solve this issue ?

Comment: @query - I added another change to this answer, you can save the current page and use it as default value if the page wasn't changed.

Comment: Now this is preventing to change the page .at first it loads the selected number of records after that always keep in same page!Your previous answer was little bit better except i was not getting live onchange effect.According to Onload  selected option all pages showed same number of records as selected in that answer, but only the onchange effect was missing in every page !

Comment: @query Unfortunately I can't help with all the small details, you can open a new question, but the comments here are not the place for this. There are lot of possible solutions.